# Rounding to nearest min in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to round the hh:mm:ss values in my TimeStamp col of the dataframe so that the seconds are always 00

Dataset:

```
    TimeStamp      A             B             C  
    10:27:30      1.953036     2.110234     1.981548      
    10:28:30      1.973408     2.046361     1.806923    
    10:29:30      0.000000     0.000000     0.014881        
    10:30:30      2.567976     3.169928     3.479591
```

I tried:

```
    df_sr4500.TimeStamp = np.asarray(np.round(df_sr4500.TimeStamp.values / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')), dtype='timedelta64[m]')
```

I get:

```
    TimeStamp        A           B             C                    
    10:28:00      1.953036     2.110234     1.981548     
    10:28:00      1.973408     2.046361     1.806923    
    10:30:00      0.000000     0.000000     0.014881      
    10:30:00      2.567976     3.169928     3.479591
```

I would have it rather rounding one way for the middle value.
The next step for me is to resample every two min with mean

Please suggest if you have any better/easier way to do this. I am very new to pandas/numpy.

Comment: Can you please add your expected output? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: I just want the 'TimeStamp' to consistently round up or round down instead of rounding to the closest even number for 30s @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one nanosecond to each time and then round.

```
df['TimeStamp'] = (df['TimeStamp'] + pd.Timedelta(1)).dt.round('min')

0   10:28:00
1   10:29:00
2   10:30:00
3   10:31:00
Name: TimeStamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I got if you check my question. I wanted it to round up or down consistently for the middle number @Ted Petrou . Thanks for trying to simplify the code though

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work for me; it gives me the following format for all the times now   10:28:30.00000

Comment: You can try adding millisecods. Use `unit='ms` but I will give you a verbose way.

Comment: You didn't reassign it